# MySql Select all data from column and count

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, iis

I am selecting with this Command all the rows from column:

```
SELECT city From Users
```

With this i am getting all the cities from my table.

Now i want to select all the column data and the count for each one.for example:

```
New York 20
Los angeles 46
London 35
```

What should be the command for this?

Comment: What is your table structure. What columns do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT City, COUNT(Field)
FROM Users
GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT City, COUNT(*)
    FROM Users
GROUP BY City
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select city, 
       count(*) 
from users 
group by city
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know your column names, you can use a structure like;

From [`MySQL - Count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement.

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city)
FROM Users
GROUP BY city
```

Here a [**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/def91/1).

```
|        CITY | COUNT |
-----------------------
|      London |    10 |
| Los angeles |    10 |
|    New York |     8 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Count` for this:

```
SELECT `city`,
 COUNT(*)
 FROM `users`
GROUP BY `city`;
```